# Pre-load and persist Durandal views

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, durandal

I'm writing a SPA with a few different views. All of the views will present results from a search so therefore it would be easier if they could all be populated upon receiving search result. It would also speed up things a bit if I didn't have to render each view upon enter. For example one of the views contains a map that would benefit from some pre-loading (and not benefit much from re-rendering).

I'm thinking of using Durandal and investigating whether its possible to both pre-load Durandal views and to keep them loaded upon switching views so that I can access DOM elements in any view at any time.

Is it possible to pre-load views and keep them loaded in Durandal? If so, how would I do that?

Note that I'm new to Durandal.

Answer (score 0):

Why cannot you use hide and show css properties rather than using views? Since all your "views" are getting populated from the same data model. Durandal will unattach the view from DOM on deactivate and reattach it when the view is activated again. This means that the view must be re-rendered by the web browser and knockout will have to re-apply all the binding on DOM elements.

Comment: You mean not use Durandal? That is the fallback plan, but I thought it would be beneficial to use some sort of framework. It has controller, router, events, transitions, etc.

Comment: If all that you want to do is have a few views that are sharing data from the same data model and need to binded at the same time then "Yes" I am saying not to use Durandal.

Comment: The app is fairly big and will have a lot of html + multiple developers working on it, so the include system in Durandal for example would be beneficial for the project.

Comment: I don't know if Durandal currently supports this feature. From what I have read on durandal's documentation and other questions that have been asked in both SO and google groups, I understand that it will remove the view from the DOM and attach it back when the view comes back. This would mean that the view must be re-rendered. However, I don't think rendering is such a big performance hit. If your view is taking too much time to render then it must be dealt outside of durandal's scope and should be a different issue. Rendering should not be an expensive or time consuming option at all.

Answer (score 0):

Durandal will not download the same template multiple times as it's using requirejs and the [text](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#text) plugin to do the actual loading. That makes the performance hit less of a concern, especially on later visits when those files are coming from the cache. In addition, it may be possible to use the [requirejs optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) to package up your templates into a single file, though I have never tried to do this myself.

Durandal does have an option on it's composition module called [cacheViews](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Composition/), found under Additional Settings which might be worth looking into. It does not preload the templates, but it does allow you to avoid reattaching them. It's an optimization that doesn't work in the general case (which is why it's opt-in), but it might work for your scenario.

However, loading external views is the way Durnadal's composition is intended to be used (though it looks like Durandal [might be extended to support your use case](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/durandaljs/9GqdFNmgo0k/QKAfrdNU8uYJ)). If you're going to preload your templates, it's worth considering not using the compose binding and just using [knockout's template binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) directly. You'll loose some of the [life cycle management](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks/) that Durandal enables for you, but if you're considering dropping Durandal entirely, I don't think that will be much of an issue. And either way, recreating it isn't too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with text.js - a RequireJS plugin.
So i modified it for my usage to do preload template logic.

I have created an example of it.
[my coder wall blog](https://coderwall.com/p/zhcqaa)
[Example code](https://github.com/gogocat/Sample-Durandal-preload-template)